# Form and subform

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

How can I set a subform to open in data entry mode when opened by pressing button 1 from another form and open the same subform in view mode when pressed button 2. Right now not only the subform but the main form also goes into data entry mode. So how can I make the subform to change based on the buttons pressed.

Comment: Set subform DateEntry property to Yes.

Comment: And can I make the same subform to show me the datas when I tell it to open it in read only mode by pressing button 2. Because when I make the data entry property of subform to yes then after clicking button 2 which tells it to show in readonly it shows me a blank subform, zero data.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more explicit: Use VBA to programmatically set the DataEntry property to True or False.

Comment: Do you want the form opened as a subform in both cases?

Comment: So what is code behind buttons to open main form? Edit your question.

Comment: Sorry I am using a macro to open the main form. How can I use VBA to programmatically set the data Entry property of the subform to True Or False based on buttons pressed. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish is to use OpenArgs.

Code in Button1.

`DoCmd.OpenForm "YourMainFormName",,,,,,"Button1"`

Code in Button2.

`DoCmd.OpenForm "YourMainFormName",,,,,,"Button2"`

Code in main form Load event.

`Me.YourSubformContainerName.Form.DataEntry = IIf(Me.OpenArgs = "Button1", True, False)`

Comment: I am getting error if I am pass the value like this:        DoCmd.OpenForm "FrmGeneXpertAdd", , , "PatientID = " & PatientID, , , , , , "btnRegister"

Comment: What error? Did you change DataEntry line to also use string "btnRegister"? Don't use filter criteria for button that should open form for DataEntry True.